# Java Swing controlling height of JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing

I want to control the height of a progress bar.
I am using the following code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
JLabel label = new JLabel("Some text");
JPanel jpb = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());    jpb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

//progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,));
progressBar.setForeground(Color.RED);
progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,3));
progressBar.setValue(40);
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

jpb.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(jpb);
```

But the progressbar sticks out like a dragon. Please recommend a solution.

Comment: You add the progress bar to the `CENTER` of a BorderLayout, so it will take all the available space. You need to better understand the use of a BorderLayout and a GridLayout. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. Maybe forget about your GridLayout and just use the default BorderLayout manager of the frame and add the progress bar to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START and then you add your second panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use GridBagLayout.
1. Use a Jpanel and set Borderlayout(already done in your code)
2. Make another JPanel and set GridBagLayout with 1 row and 3 column in it.
3. Post 2nd JPanel at the center of 1st JPanel.
4. Add your JProgressbar to 1st column
5. Set the size of column as per your visual needs for width and height of JProgressbar

Hope this will be helpful. :-)